# How to name parameter of callback in JSDoc

Tags: function, jsdoc

I wrote this simple function and its documentation :

```
/**
 * @function foo
 * @param {function(*): *} callback
 * @returns
 */
function foo(callback){
    return callback()
}
```

It just takes another function in argument, executes it, and returns its result.

It produces `function foo(callback: (arg0: any) => any): any` (at least in VSCode).

How can I **rename arg0** here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe the callback function (and its parameters) with a `@callback` tag e.g.

[image]